# tkinter: binding a function to a button that opens a simpledialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write a program using tk inter that stores a user's contacts (name and phone number) in a "phonebook", but also allows the user to add new contacts. I would like to bind the "addcontact" button to a function that opens a simple dialog asking the user to enter a new name and phone number they want to add. I would then take this information and display it in the "phonebook". However, everytime I run my code I get the spinning wheel of death and nothing loads. Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

def contact(event = None):
    phonenum = listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
    numString.set("Phone Number" + ":" + " " + phonenumbers[phonenum])

def add(event = None):
    application_window = tk.Tk()
    answer = simpledialog.askstring("String", "Enter name, phone number", parent=application_window)

root = Tk()
root.title("Contacts")
phonenumbers = {"John" : "201-453-4324", "Stacy" : "201-453-3564", "Tim" : "832-143-5345", "Maria" : "503-675-3322"}
contacts = phonenumbers.keys()
listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

for c in contacts:
    listbox.insert(END, c)

#Output phone number
numString = StringVar()
numLabel = Label(root, textvariable = numString)
numLabel.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 1)

 #Buttons
contactButton = Button(root, text = "Contact Info")
contactButton.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
contactButton.bind("<Button-1>", contact)
addButton = contactButton = Button(root, text = "Add Contact")
addButton.bind("<Button-1>", add)
addButton.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Tk()` is something you should only call once.  I have no idea why you're doing it each time you click the Add button.

Comment: You normally shouldn't use `bind` with a button. Instead, set the `command` attribute of the button.

Comment: thank you, deleted that and it runs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that extra `Tk()` call and you don't need to set the parent window. Also, you should use the command argument for the button rather than binding:

```
def add(event = None):
    answer = simpledialog.askstring("String", "Enter name, phone number")

addButton = tk.Button(root, text = "Add Contact", command=add)
```